# Can ImageMagick return the convert result

Tags: image, unix, image-processing, command-line, imagemagick-convert

I'm using ImageMagick from the command line to convert pdf to image

```
convert -density 300x300 -resize 800x600 -quality 85 1.pdf[1,2,3] ZIEL.jpg
```

However, I don't know the result of this operation.this command has nothing output,can anyone know how to get result of convert?

Comment: Because JPEG is a single-image format, the output should be the images ZIEL-0.jpg, ZIEL-1.jpg, and ZIEL-2.jpg.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson

because of this command was called by other script,
so i need to get result of convert from output.
how to get result string like "ZIEL-0.jpg, ZIEL-1.jpg, and ZIEL-2.jpg"?

when call this command again the output should be "ZIEL-1-0.jpg, ZIEL-1-1.jpg, and ZIEL-1-2.jpg",so walk output directory for get convert result is incorrect way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use convert's "-verbose" option to see what is happening:

```
convert -verbose -density 300x300 -resize 800x600 -quality 85 logo: logo: ZIEL.jpg
LOGO GIF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 28.6KB 0.020u 0:00.019
logo:=>LOGO GIF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 28.6KB 0.000u 0:00.000
LOGO GIF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 28.6KB 0.020u 0:00.029
logo:=>LOGO GIF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 28.6KB 0.000u 0:00.000
logo:=>ZIEL-0.jpg[0] GIF 640x480=>800x600 800x600+0+0 8-bit sRGB 42KB 0.340u 0:00.330
logo:=>ZIEL-1.jpg[1] GIF 640x480=>800x600 800x600+0+0 8-bit sRGB 42KB 0.210u 0:00.210
```

Because JPEG is a single-image format, the output is in separate images ZIEL-0.jpg, ZIEL-1.jpg, etc.